# Getting the full link with rvest href

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape multiple pages with `rvest`. However, the link I get through `html_attr("href")` is incomplete. The intial part of the link unfortunately changes across pages in a way that I am unable to understand. Do you know if there is a solution? Thank you.

These are two examples of the website. The part that changes across pages seems to be "/sk####". (I am interested in the links to the *Relazione* and *Testo articoli* pages.

http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/stampati/sk5000/frontesp/4543.htm

http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/stampati/sk4500/frontesp/4477.htm

```
df <- structure(list(date = c(20010618L, 20010618L, 20010618L, 20010618L, 
                        20010618L), link = c("http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/schedela/trovastampatopdl.asp?pdl=814", 
                                                  "http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/schedela/trovastampatopdl.asp?pdl=858", 
                                                  "http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/schedela/trovastampatopdl.asp?pdl=875", 
                                                  "http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/schedela/trovastampatopdl.asp?pdl=802", 
                                                  "http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/schedela/trovastampatopdl.asp?pdl=816"
                        )), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")


df$linkfinal<- pbsapply(df$link, function(x) {
  tryCatch({
    x %>%
      read_html() %>%
      html_nodes('td+ td a') %>%
      html_attr("href") %>% 
      toString()
  }, error = function(e) NA)
})
```

Comment: Could you share a bit of your R object so we can better understand your `df` object? You could use `dput(head(df, 5))` and paste the result into your question.

Comment: Thanks; I included an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to capture the re-direct url (use `httr`), then swop out the string `frontesp` with either `articola` or `relazion`. If you first use these same substrings to test if the href containing this is present, you can leverage ifelse to either do the url substitution described above or return NA.

There are faster ways of applying a function if working with large numbers of rows. I was just interested in this approach after reading about it here: https://blog.az.sg/posts/map-and-walk/.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)

df <- structure(list(date = c(
  20010618L, 20010618L, 20010618L, 20010618L,
  20010618L
), link = c(
  "http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/schedela/trovastampatopdl.asp?pdl=814",
  "http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/schedela/trovastampatopdl.asp?pdl=858",
  "http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/schedela/trovastampatopdl.asp?pdl=875",
  "http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/schedela/trovastampatopdl.asp?pdl=802",
  "http://leg14.camera.it/_dati/leg14/lavori/schedela/trovastampatopdl.asp?pdl=816"
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")


get_link <- function(url, page, url_sub_string) {
  link <- page %>%
    html_element(sprintf("[href*=%s]", url_sub_string)) %>%
    html_attr("href")
  link <- ifelse(is.na(link), link, gsub("frontesp", url_sub_string, url))
  return(link)
}

df <- df %>%
  pmap_dfr(function(...) {
    current <- tibble(...)
    r <- GET(current$link)
    page <- r %>% read_html()
    redirect_link <- r$url
    current %>%
      mutate(
        articola = get_link(redirect_link, page, "articola"),
        relazion = get_link(redirect_link, page, "relazion")
      )
  })
```